# How to use line breaks in VBA for an outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to separate this messages as salutation, body, and signature using VBA in excel that will make an automatic outlook email. But I can't separate each one of them using line breaks. Care to help?

```
Dim MyOutlook As Object
Set MyOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


Dim MyMail As Object
Set MyMail = MyOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

MyMail.To = "sampleemail@google.com"
MyMail.CC = "sampleemail@google.com"enter code here
MyMail.Subject = "Sample Subject"
MyMail.Body = "Hello Team," & _
              "Please see attached for this month's summary" & _
              "Thanks!" & _
              "Sample Signature"
Attached_File = "C:\Users\public\Documents\sample_reports.xls"

MyMail.Attachments.Add Attached_File

MyMail.Send

End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `<br>`.

Comment: If <br> doesn't work, try appending `vbNewLine` to the end of your lines in `.Body`

Answer (score 1):

use vbNewLine

```
MyMail.Body =  "Hello Team," & vbNewLine & _
               "Please see attached for this month's summary" & vbNewLine & _
               "Thanks!" & vbNewLine & _
               "Sample Signature"
```